# How to add Scheduler and Trigger to a nested template in Azure devops pipeline?

Tags: templates, azure-devops, yaml

I am new to Azure devops and would like your suggestion. I have a main azure-pipeline.yml that refers a nested template (azure-pipeline-e2e.yml) file. Basically, when the main azure-pipeline.yml runs , it triggers the nested template wherein if the branch is not master, nested template jobs will be skipped.

Query:

I want the nested template to be run as part of overnight schedule. I also want this nested pipeline to have no trigger(trigger:none).... Please note that current set up works fine. Only When I add scheduler jobs and trigger jobs in the nested template, the main azure-pipeline.yml complains that Scheduler and Trigger commands are unknown? Please advise on how to have both the trigger and Scheduler in the nested pipeline such that main pipeline does not complain

Current setup:
main azure-pipeline.yml file

```html
trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: EDEA

stages:
- stage: dev
  jobs:
  - job: build_test_deploy_UI_to_DEV
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '12.x'
        etc.....

- stage: e2e
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')) 
  displayName: 'Run e2e Tests'
  jobs:
  - template: 'azure-pipelines-e2e.yml'

- stage: dtc
  jobs:
    - job: build_and_deploy_UI_to_DTC
      steps:
        - task: NodeTool@0
          displayName: 'Install Node.js'
          inputs:
            versionSpec: '12.x'
            etc.....
```

nested template (azure-pipeline-e2e.yml)

```html
jobs:
- job: run_e2e_tests
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')) 
  steps: 
  - task: SecretsManagerGetSecret@1
    displayName: Get AWS  secrets
    inputs:
      awsCredentials: 'project.dev.Aws'
      regionName: 'eu-central-1'
      secretIdOrName: 'secretname'
      variableName: 'tempvariable'
```

Basically, in the nested template above, When I add scheduler and Trigger jobs, nested template does not complain. But the main azure pipeline complains that Scheduler and Trigger comands are unknown

Proposed: azure-pipeline-e2e.yml

```html
schedules:
  - cron: "0 0 * * *"
    displayName: Daily midnight build
    branches:
      include:
        - master
    always: true

trigger: none

    jobs:
    - job: run_e2e_tests
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')) 
      steps: 
      - task: SecretsManagerGetSecret@1
        displayName: Get AWS  secrets
        inputs:
          awsCredentials: 'project.dev.Aws'
          regionName: 'eu-central-1'
          secretIdOrName: 'secretname'
          variableName: 'tempvariable'
```

Answer (score 0):

The main pipeline complains about `trigger` and `schedule` parameters because it expects only jobs defined inside the nested template. In the current example you provided, by defining those 2 parameters in the template results into the main pipeline being something like this:

```
[...]
- stage: e2e
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')) 
  displayName: 'Run e2e Tests'
  jobs:
  schedules:
   - cron: "0 0 * * *"
     displayName: Daily midnight build
     branches:
       include:
       - master
     always: true
  trigger: none
  - job:
[...]
```

... and that obviously is not the correct syntax.

The best workaround for this would probably be to include the `schedule` inside the main pipeline and add run condition `eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')` for the stages that need to be executed when the build is triggered by the schedule.
The result would look similar to this: (main) azure-pipelines.yml

```
 schedules:
 - cron: "0 0 * * *"
   displayName: Daily midnight build
   branches:
     include:
     - master
   always: true
 trigger:
 - master
 pool:
   name: EDEA

 stages:
   [...]
 - stage: e2e
   condition: or(and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')) 
   displayName: 'Run e2e Tests'
   jobs:
   - template: 'azure-pipelines-e2e.yml'
```

You will also need the same run condition inside the nested template.

Comment: Thanks LJ for your comments. Appreciate it. What about the 'trigger:none' in the nested template?  ie. how do I set up my nested template such that it does not get triggered.. Currently when there is a checkin to my feature branch (main pipeline) , nested pipeline gets triggered and job within the nested template is skipped as it is not a master branch. Basically, I want the nested template not to be triggered at all...Again, appreciate your help!!!

Comment: `stage: e2e` along with the nested pipeline will be triggered with every run since it's a part of the main pipeline that is pre-loaded when the whole build is triggered. If the run conditions are defined correctly, there is no need to worry because jobs in the nested pipeline will always be skipped if conditions don't match.

Comment: One more thing. I'm not familiar with your whole workflow, but if `stage: e2e` is the only stage in the whole pipeline that needs to be executed with schedule, then you need to add `ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')` for every other stage in the main pipeline because scheduled run most likely will be based on master branch and that will trigger all other stages with condition `eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')`

Answer (score 0):

The triggers should be defined in the main yaml azure pipeline instead of the nested template yaml.

And the template yaml will be triggered along with the main yaml pipeline. All you can do is to keep the stage from being executed by skipping it. You can achieve this by adding the condition `eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')` to the stage that needs to be executed on the schedule mentioned by LJ.. See [condtions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more information.

If only the e2e stage needs to be run in the scheduled build, you can also try creating another yaml pipeline to run the jobs in the template yaml. Then you can define the scheduled triggers in the new yaml pipeline, and this pipeline is only triggered on the schedule.